# css giving me errors and i don't understand why when using media screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 `@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
display: flex;
justify-content: spacebetween;
height: 80px;

}`
```

whilst folloiwng a tutorial from brian design as a someone who is trying to learn web development i came across this error which states constantly says my code is invalid giving me errors.For eacho f these erros it says that i should be using a curly bracked on line 2,3,4 but i don't understand why as the code above it is fine but this one has a problem.I have tried looking online to go find an answer and even read some documentation but i still am struggling to find out the route cause of this problem could someone help me

Comment: `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: You also need an element to apply this properties (id,class,etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

A rule (a property with a value) must be contained in a ruleset (a selector followed by { then some rules then }).

A ruleset can appear inside or outside of a media query.

Your media query contains rules directly without the required ruleset. (You might be trying to put the media query in a ruleset, which also isn’t allowed).

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the element you want to style too:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .some-element-you-want-to-style {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
     }
}
```